# DSE Cassandra 4.8.4 not a valid port number

Tags: linux, cassandra, cqlsh

I have a four node cluster and am trying to get node 1 up and running.

Version of Cassandra: DSE Cassandra 4.8.4

The syntax that I am using to log into cqlsh is:

```
cqlsh -u cassandra -pw cassandra 10.30.30.243 9160
```

And the output that I am receiving is as follows:

> Usage: cqlsh [options] [host [port]]
>
> cqlsh: error: '10.30.30.243' is not a valid port number.

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: I don't know anything from cqlsh, but in similar cases my next try would be to leave the spaces after `-u` and `-pw`.

Comment: Let me make this a question. Why does the correct syntax provided by the OP produce the error message instead of starting CQLSH as desired?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want just `-p` for the password its picking up the cassandra as the host then using the host as the port.

Try

```
cqlsh -u cassandra -p cassandra 10.30.30.243
```

You shouldn't need the port since thats the default port.

Comment: I tried this and the -pw is required syntax. If the port number is not included the same error message is produced, exactly the way described in the OP statement.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have spent way to much time dis-assembling object code. It is really a treat to have source code. Here is what I did in bin/cqlsh.py, near line 2350 I added:

```
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

Just before lines:

```
hostname = environment.get('CQLSH_HOST', hostname)
port = environment.get('CQLSH_PORT', port)
```

Keep in mind indentation is important to Python, it seems, if you get errors.

Debug using commands 'p hostname' and 'p port', use 'n' to step forward.

You can read the code, there are just a few lines to here:

```
    (Pdb) n
> /usr/local/c4/cassandra/bin/cqlsh.py(2368)read_options()
-> if optvalues.color in (True, False):
(Pdb) p port
'192.168.1.3:9042'
```

You can see "port" has become the IP address and the port, step on down to the try
and step through it:

```
    -> try: (Pdb) n
> /usr/local/c4/cassandra/bin/cqlsh.py(2383)read_options()
-> port = int(port) (Pdb) p port '192.168.1.3:9042' (Pdb) n ValueError: "invalid literal for int() with base 10: '192.168.1.3:9042'"
> /usr/local/c4/cassandra/bin/cqlsh.py(2383)read_options()
-> port = int(port)
```

So there you have it:

```
    > /usr/local/c4/cassandra/bin/cqlsh.py(2384)read_options()
-> except ValueError:
(Pdb) n
> /usr/local/c4/cassandra/bin/cqlsh.py(2385)read_options()
-> parser.error('%r is not a valid port number.' % port)
(Pdb) n
Usage: cqlsh.py [options] [host [port]]

cqlsh.py: error: '192.168.1.3:9042' is not a valid port number.
SystemExit: 2
> /usr/local/c4/cassandra/bin/cqlsh.py(2385)read_options()
-> parser.error('%r is not a valid port number.' % port)
```

I ran it with

```
bin/cqlsh -u cassandra -pw cassandra 192.168.1.3 9042

p len(arguments) 3 
p arguments[0] 'cassandra' 
p arguments[1]  '192.168.1.3' 
p arguments[2] '9042'

> /usr/local/c4/cassandra/bin/cqlsh.py(2386)read_options()
-> parser.error('%r is not a valid port number.' % port)
(Pdb) p port
'192.168.1.3
```

I took a look at how parsing works in Python, the cqlsh.py parsing routine is expecting:

```
parser.add_option("-p", "--password", help="Authenticate using password.")
```

bin/cqlsh -u cassandra -p cassandra 192.168.1.3 9042

Now the parser is plenty happy

```
--Return--
> /usr/local/c4/cassandra/bin/cqlsh.py(2386)read_options()->(<Values at 0x...owser': None}>, '192.168.1.3', 9042)
-> return options, hostname, port
```

Now to figure out what is happening to the credentials; keeping mind I am not changing the Python, I am just feeding it various input.

> AuthenticationFailed(...e=0100 [Bad credentials] message="Provided
>   username cassandra and/or password are incorrect

Stepping through

> https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/optparse.py

Password is parsed correctly with -p and stored off in 'password'.
The IP address and the port are good in

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/optparse.py(1405)parse_args()->(<Values at 0x...owser': None}>, ['192.168.1.3', '9042'])
```

Which brings us to naturally back to right where we left cqlsh.py

```
/usr/local/c4/cassandra/bin/cqlsh.py(2339)read_options()
-> hostname = option_with_default(configs.get, 'connection', 'hostname', DEFAULT_HOST)
```

Everything looks really good and then we hit some errors not seen before

```
(Pdb) p len(arguments)
2
(Pdb) p arguments
['192.168.1.3', '9042']
(Pdb) n
NoSectionError: No secti...nnection'
> /usr/local/c4/cassandra/bin/cqlsh.py(2258)option_with_default()
-> return cparser_getter(section, option)
(Pdb) n
> /usr/local/c4/cassandra/bin/cqlsh.py(2259)option_with_default()
-> except ConfigParser.Error:
(Pdb) n
> /usr/local/c4/cassandra/bin/cqlsh.py(2260)option_with_default()
-> return default
(Pdb) p len(arguments)
2
(Pdb) p arguments
['192.168.1.3', '9042']
```

Yet the arguments and the count still look perfect and in fact are returned as we saw above previously. Stepping on through from here shows this section is driven three times and produces the error each time.

```
NoSectionError: No secti...nnection'
    > /usr/local/c4/cassandra/bin/cqlsh.py(2258)option_with_default()
    -> return cparser_getter(section, option)
    (Pdb) n
    > /usr/local/c4/cassandra/bin/cqlsh.py(2259)option_with_default()
    -> except ConfigParser.Error:
```

My speculation at this point; The call to ConfigParser is having an undesired effect on the user or password field which were stored away nicely earlier. I expect the problem can be tracked down but I am out of time for this effort so I will leave that up to the professionals.

For now I have gone back to

> authenticator: AllowAllAuthenticator in cassandra.yaml where
>
> > bin/cqlsh 192.168.1.3 9042

drops me right in to CQLSH.